# brew update failes because of deletion of system installed Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, rvm, homebrew

brew update failes with the error

> /usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory /usr/local/bin/brew: line 23: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0"

I have deleted `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework` bacause of some Ruby conflicts. I know this was a big mistake.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Fixed this temporarily by copying /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework from a different machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reinstall Ruby. I am assuming you are using Mac OSX? Download the OS from the store and just install the essentials.pkg as shown [here](https://superuser.com/a/866113).

Would also recommend you use [RVM](https://rvm.io/).